# Symfony 2.8 to 3.3 migration on dev annotation not loaded

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, migration, autoload

I'm on migration 2.8 => 3.3
I used this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/mickaelandrieu/5d27a2ffafcbdd64912f549aaf2a6df9)
But when I'm trying to clear cache on `dev` I catch this Exceprion:

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>     [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route" in class AppBundle\Controller\Applicati
>     onController does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

But on `prod` all works fine:

> // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false

My app.php

```
<?php

 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

 require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
 if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
     include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
 }

 $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
 if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
     $kernel->loadClassCache();
 }
 $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
 $response = $kernel->handle($request);
 $response->send();
 $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

app_dev.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
   $kernel->loadClassCache();
}
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I really not understand why all works on `prod` and fail on `dev`

require

```
    "symfony/symfony": "3.3.15",
    "symfony/validator": "3.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1.6",
```